# Extracting 2D Matrix from 3D Matrix for Schur Decompostion in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, scipy

Is it possible to perform Schur Decomposition on a 3D matrix in Python without using a loop? The function requires a square matrix for input. E.g.

```
  #Matrix  A of size (N,M,M)

  schur=np.array(scipy.linalg.schur(A[:,:,:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

No.
`scipy.linalg.schur` only accepts 2D arrays. You'll need to loop over the sub-arrays manually.